# Is it right, my understanding about (order and sense) stationarity?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Before writing this post, I want to say thank you for every people who answered and commented to me. Thanks to mathematicians being active in this site, I think that I finally understood a little more than before about stationarity of random process.

---

### In first-order stationarity,

A continuous-time random process $\{X(t), t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is strict-sense stationary if
$$
\forall t_1\in\mathbb{R}, \forall \Delta\in\mathbb{R},\\
F_{X(t_1)}(x_1) = F_{X(t_1+\Delta)}(x_1) 
$$

A continuous-time random process $\{X(t), t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is wide-sense stationary if
$$
E[X(t_1)]=E[X(t_1+\Delta)]\\
$$

---

### In second-order stationarity,

A continuous-time random process $\{X(t), t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is strict-sense stationary if
$$
\forall t_1, t_2\in\mathbb{R}, \forall \Delta\in\mathbb{R},\\
F_{X(t_1)X(t_2)}(x_1, x_2) = F_{X(t_1+\Delta)X(t_2+\Delta)}(x_1, x_2) 
$$

A continuous-time random process $\{X(t), t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is wide-sense stationary if
$$
E[X(t_1)]=E[X(t_2)]\\
E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]=E[X(t_1+\Delta)X(t_2+\Delta)]
$$

---

### In n-th-order stationarity,

A continuous-time random process $\{X(t), t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is strict-sense stationary if
$$
\forall t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_n\in\mathbb{R}, \forall \Delta\in\mathbb{R},\\
F_{X(t_1)X(t_2)\cdots X(t_n)}(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) = F_{X(t_1+\Delta)X(t_2+\Delta)\cdots X(t_n+\Delta)}(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) 
$$

A continuous-time random process $\{X(t), t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is wide-sense stationary if
$$
E[X(t_1)]=E[X(t_2)]\\
E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]=E[X(t_1+\Delta)X(t_2+\Delta)]\\
E[X(t_1)X(t_2)X(t_3)]=E[X(t_1+\Delta)X(t_2+\Delta)X(t_3+\Delta)]\\
\cdots\\
E[X(t_1)X(t_2)\cdots X(t_n)]=E[X(t_1+\Delta)X(t_2+\Delta)\cdots X(t_n+\Delta)]
$$

---

Just order is how many ***JOINT*** there exist.

Strict-sense is a perspective on ***PDF (CDF)***.

Wide-sense is a perspective on ***Expectation***.

Right? I do hope I'm right.

Comment: @JKnecht ah, I incognized about vote-up. Thank you for noticing that function. From now on, I will do that thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No i dont think you are right.

I will mainly focus on wide-sense stationarity and i will use
a different notation, from Probability and Random Processes by Grimmet and Stirzaker which is a commonly used book.
But i think you will understand.

---

> **Def:**
>
> The process $X = \{X(t):\: t \geq 0\}$, taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, is called strictly stationary if the families
>
> $$\{X(t_1), X(t_2),..., X(t_n)\}\:\: \text{and} \:\: \{X(t_1+h), X(t_2+h),..., X(t_n+h)\}\:\:\:\: (*)$$
>
> have the same joint distribution for all $t_1, t_2,...,t_n$ and $h > 0$.

---

> **Def:**
>
> The process $X = \{X(t):\: t \geq 0\}$ is called wide-sense (or second order) stationary if, for all $t_1, t_2$ and $h > 0$
>
> $$E(X(t_1)) = E(X(t_2))\:\: \text{and} \:\: \text{cov}(X(t_1),X(t_2)) = \text{cov}(X(t_1 + h),X(t_2 + h))$$

---

If the stationary condition $(*)$ of a random process $X(t)$ does not hold for all $n$ but holds for $n \leq k$, then we say that the process $X(t)$ is stationary to order $k$. If $X(t)$ is stationary to order $2$, then $X(t)$ is said to be wide-sense stationary (WSS). If $X(t)$ is a WSS random process, then we have

$1.$ $E[X(t)]  = \mu$ (constant)

$2.$ $R_x(t_1, t_2) = E[X(t_1)X(t_2)] = R_X(|t_2 - t_1|) = R_X(\tau)$

WSS processes are completely characterized by only the first- and second-order distributions.

$\mu$ does not depend on $t$ since $F_{X(t)}(x)$ does not depend on $t$ and $R_X(t, t+\tau)$ does not depend on $t$ since $F_{X(t), X(t + \tau)}(x_1, x_2)$ does not depend on $t$.

And strict sense stationary $\Rightarrow$ WSS obviously.

Comment: I've seen that definition from other web-pages. As I read the definitions, I started to think that order and sense is totally different things. A n-th order strict-sense stationary process is that n-joint probability is same as n-joint probability shifted some time. And a n-th order wide-sense stationary process is that expectation of multiplications of X is same as expectation of multiplications of X shifted some time.

Comment: I have never heard of n-th order wide sense stationary processes. Where have you read about those?

Comment: Just I guessed :)

Comment: @Danny_Kim Ok, then maybe we can agree on that a wide-sense-stationary (WSS) process is a second-order process which has a constant mean and whose autocorrelation function depends only on the time difference $\tau$

Comment: Actually, I was really wondering about relationship between order and sense-wise.

Comment: @Danny_Kim Sense is just a word as in strict sense stationary and wide sense stationary. Strictly stationary is the same as strict sense stationary. There is no relationship between sense and order.

Comment: Also, in all of the above, including my answer, i am assuming processes with finite second moments.